# Intuitive explanation for $E[X]=\int_{0}^\infty P(X\ge x) dx$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have come across two proofs for this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), but I cannot wrap my head around the intuition behind this. Why should this hold?

I am looking for a possible geometric interpretation of the area under the curve.